# How to get Banshee to see Xoom via MTP?

Tags: linux, motorola-xoom

I just bought a Canadian region Xoom, and have been able to access it via MTP using Gnomad2, but Banshee refuses to recognize it, despite having the libmtp extension installed. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

OS: Fedora 14, amd64

Comment: What is Banshee?

Comment: @Matthew: It's a media player/manager. [Website](http://banshee.fm/)